# Adding time deltas to a running total in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

[image]

So I have two columns of data in my dataframe.  TimeDeltasDiffs and ActualTime.  First row of the dataframe has a start time in the ActualTime column.  I want to populate the ActualTime column incrementally based on a time delta value in the current row.

I've used apply and lambdas for other operations on this dataframe. e.g.

```
df_mrx['Log Timestamp'] = df_mrx['Log Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: '00:' + x)
```

But not sure how to use that based on previous values as I am iterating ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, the value of the nth row in column ActualTime is the value of the nth - 1 row of ActualTime plus the value of the nth row of TimeDeltasDiffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to use .apply(). Consider below approach.
Given that below is the `df`

```
       ActualTime           TimeDeltasDiffs
0   2018-04-16 17:06:01      00:00:00
1        0                   00:00:01
2        0                   00:00:00
3        0                   00:00:02
```

You need to use [.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) on `TimeDeltasDiffs`

```
df['ActualTime'] = df.iloc[0]['ActualTime']
df['ActualTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ActualTime']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeDeltasDiffs']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
         ActualTime            TimeDeltasDiffs
0   2018-04-16 17:06:01           00:00:00
1   2018-04-16 17:06:02           00:00:01
2   2018-04-16 17:06:02           00:00:00
3   2018-04-16 17:06:04           00:00:02
```